# Why is IIS asking for NTLM over and over

Tags: iis, ntlm

When running a website localy on IIS every request requires NTLM authentication over again.

When running on server it's not as bad, but still requests more than once for a batch of requests all used for loading one page.

I found a question which is [Similar, but different](https://serverfault.com/questions/358071/all-client-browsers-repeatedly-asking-for-ntlm-authentication-when-running-throu).

My requests have `Connection: keep-alive`

All requests have `ASP.NET_SessionId` set to same value, why would some need authentication while others don't?

Trying to make sense of it...

Answer (score 0):

This can occur if AuthPersistSingleRequest=False or if the tcp connection is initiated from a different source port on the client. If subsequent connections originate from a different port, it will result in a new challenge.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabh_singh/archive/2010/01/06/case-study-are-you-seeing-401-s-too-often-for-http-web-requests.aspx